# VS BuildBundlerMinifier compile errors in site.min.css Expect comma, found '/'

Tags: css, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019, bundler

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 for an ASP.net Core solution, and `BuildBundlerMinfier` is used to to bundle js and css files on build.

if I have something like this in my css files that I include in the `bundleconfig.json`:

```
rgb(26 179 232 / 15%)
rgb(60 64 67 / 30%)
```

when I try to build I'll get this kind of compile errors for `site.min.css` (bundler output file):

```
Expect comma, found '179'  
Expect comma, found '64'  
Expect comma, found '/'
```

and my only solution for now is to not use this bundler for css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution that's right for you:

```
rgba(26, 179, 232, 0.15)
rgba(60, 64, 67, 0.30)
```

Hope I was helpful!

Comment: so instead of `rgb(... /15%`, I should use `rgba( ... 0.15` and it would be the same css, just no VS errors ?

Comment: @buga Exactly! :)